# Восстановить историю коммитов, git

Tags: git

Есть папка .git на проекте. Как восстановить историю коммитов и залить всю историю на новый репозиторий?

```
$ git log 

Fatal: Reference has invalid format: 'refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Comment: У вас `git log` ничего не выводит или что происходит?

Comment: Походу не очень выводит - Fatal: Reference has invalid format: 'refs/remotes/origin/master

Comment: Влад, попробуйте погуглить по этому сообщению об ошибке, как минимум. Но не забудьте сделать бэкап репозитория. Ну и добавьте это сообщение в формулировку вопроса.

Comment: я знаю, как получить подобную ошибку. Но вот как рассказать, как исправить...  для начала я бы открыл файл `.git/refs/remotes/origin/master` и посмотрел внутрь. Там должна быть одна строка на 40 символов плюс перевод строки. Если там не оно, тогда надо будет "фиксить".

Comment: Что показывает `git reflog`? Есть ли копии проекта у других людей или на удаленном репозитории? Что вы делали перед поломкой?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в рефлог:

```
git reflog
```

Там будет что-нибудь такое:

```
4422cf4 HEAD@{1}: pull: Fast-forward
04c196f HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from master to foo
4422cf4 HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from feature to master
9ea2227 HEAD@{4}: reset: moving to HEAD^
b6c2674 HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from bar to feature
```

Найдите сообщение подходящего вам коммита и сделайте reset на него:

```
git reset --hard 4422cf4
```

Если это не сработает, вы можете «починить» файл `.git/refs/remotes/origin/master` самостоятельно. Этот файл обозначает собой ветку `master`. Он содержит 40-символьный хеш коммита, на который смотрит ветка `master`, заканчивается переводом строки.

1. Получите полный хеш нужного коммита с помощью `rev-parse`:

   ```
   $ git rev-parse 4422cf4
   4422cf4a13713ed6c2305daeefd5105a7708fc78
   ```
2. Запишите этот текст в файл. Можно всё сделать одним действием:

   ```
   git rev-parse 4422cf4 > .git/refs/remotes/origin/master
   ```